# MongoDB remove nested objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection like this:

```
_id: {name: 'name', family: 'family'}
```

i want to remove some objects by _id using by $in, how i can do this?
for example my query should be something like:

```
db.persons.remove({_id: {$in: [ { name: 'name1', family: 'family1' }
                              , { name: 'name2', family: 'family2' }
                              ]
                        }
                 })
```

Comment: @Neil, you are right.:D actually my problem was the order of fields! if i try `db.persons.remove({_id: {$in: [{family: 'family1', name: 'name1'}]}})` nothing happened, but above query is working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do this with an [**`$or`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query and dot notation if your fields are not always in the same order:

```
db.persons.remove({
    "$or": [
        { "_id.name": "name1", "_id.family": "family1" },
        { "_id.name": "name2", "_id.family": "family2" },
    }
})
```

Not the mongoose syntax, but you get the idea. It is logically the same thing but the field order is not dependent as it is with the full object you are specifying to [**`$in`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).